Добавлене записи в таблицу dearpygui
у меня есть таблица, в которую в ходе выполнения программы необходимо вставить значение. В официальной документации я (как всегда) ничего не нашёл. Попробовал на "абум"
with dpg.table_row(parent="btable"):
        dpg.add_text(out[0])
        dpg.add_text(out[1])
        dpg.add_text(out[2])
        dpg.add_text(out[3])
        dpg.add_text(out[4])
        dpg.add_text(out[11])

таким образом не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Для начала тебе нужно инициализировать столбцы, и уже после добавлять строки, вот простой пример
def add_row_callback():
    out = ["New Value 1", "New Value 2"]
    
    with dpg.table_row(parent="btable"):
        for value in out:
            dpg.add_text(value)

with dpg.window(label="Example Table"):
    dpg.add_button(label="Add Row", callback=add_row_callback)
    
    with dpg.table(header_row=True, tag="btable"):
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Column 1")
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Column 2")

